# `ClassCastException` with Eclipse RCP Internals on 2022-12

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, classcastexception, e4

I am currently responsible for upgrading a legacy Eclipse RCP application at my job from Java 11 to Java 17. As part of this, I am upgrading from Eclipse 2018-12 to 2022-12.

However, this has introduced a runtime `ClassCastException` that I cannot seem to chase down. Specifically:

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.PartStackImpl cannot be cast to class org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.MToolControl (org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.PartStackImpl and org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.MToolControl are in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @5a5e548c)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:183)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:5960)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.DisplayUISynchronize.syncExec(DisplayUISynchronize.java:34)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.di.UIEventObjectSupplier$UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventObjectSupplier.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:133)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:44)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:63)
        at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:424)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EcoreEList.dispatchNotification(EcoreEList.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.NotifyingListImpl.addUnique(NotifyingListImpl.java:304)
        at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.AbstractEList.add(AbstractEList.java:304)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.minmax.MinMaxAddon.setState(MinMaxAddon.java:210)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.minmax.MinMaxAddon$1.minimize(MinMaxAddon.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onSelection(CTabFolder.java:2171)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.lambda$0(CTabFolder.java:341)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5855)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1529)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:5065)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4517)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1440)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.PartStackImpl cannot be cast to class org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.MToolControl (org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.PartStackImpl and org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.MToolControl are in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @5a5e548c)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.minmax.MinMaxAddon.createTrim(MinMaxAddon.java:1019)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.minmax.MinMaxAddon.minimize(MinMaxAddon.java:666)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.minmax.MinMaxAddon.subscribeTopicTagsChanged(MinMaxAddon.java:407)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
        ... 45 more
```

This occurs when I try to interact with these minimize and maximize buttons on the right of panel headers:

[image: Eclipse RCP Panel Header]

`PartStackImpl` and `MToolControl` are both part of the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench` jarfile, while `MinMaxAddon` (which is attempting the cast) is part of `org.eclipse.e4.workbench.addons.swt`. I've confirmed that both of these jarfiles are their most up-to-date versions available for 2022-12 (2.2.300 and 1.4.500 respectively, both from Oct. 2022).

Inspecting the inheritance tree for `PartStackImpl` confirms that it is indeed not a subtype of `MToolControl`, so the class cast exception makes sense. However, I am confused as to why the supposedly up-to-date `MinMaxAddon` is attempting this cast in the first place.

I have next to no experience with Eclipse RCP (the only developer who did here has long since departed), so I'm not sure if I am just missing something specific to the RCP tooling that would be obvious to someone else.

Comment: Well it looks like some sort of error in the MinMaxAddon code. It is calculating the id of what it thinks should be the trim control and then just assuming it got an MToolControl. For some reason that isn't working for you. I can't reproduce this in the standard Eclipse and I don't see a bug report for this. If you can come up with some way to reproduce this then maybe we can help.

Comment: Maybe set a breakpoint at MinMaxAddon line 1019 and see what is in the `trimId` variable - check if that id matches something in your application model.